# xampp phpmyadmin #2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

when I try to open XAMPP phpmyadmin It shows below error **(ER(1)** .before display this error **(ER(1)** phpmyadmin showed **ER(2)**, then **I installed again XAMPP 3 times**. After installation, frist time phpmyadmin worked properly  but when i refresh after crate a database, these errors are appeared.please give me a solution.

> ER(1) #2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to
>   the client
>
> ER(2) #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

There is a config.inc.php file located somewhere in the xampp directory. What you have to do is open this file in a text editor and set the password I think. I have not used xampp in years

Comment: plz let me know if I helped at all

Comment: yes ... I changed config.inc.php when phpmyadmin showed this #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). but I uninstalled this edited Xampp version.